# Apache Flink: Registration name clash. KvState with name *** has already been registered by another operator

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am facing the issue while I run the flink job.

```
Registration name clash. KvState with name 'XXXX' has already been registered by another operator (fab4c54085fa3ee85a6e1bb1062c20af).
```

**Exception:**

```
org.apache.flink.runtime.execution.SuppressRestartsException: Unrecoverable failure. This suppresses job restarts. Please check the stack trace for the root cause.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.query.KvStateLocationRegistry.notifyKvStateRegistered(KvStateLocationRegistry.java:120)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager.org$apache$flink$runtime$jobmanager$JobManager$$handleKvStateMessage(JobManager.scala:1517)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1.applyOrElse(JobManager.scala:740)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.LeaderSessionMessageFilter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(LeaderSessionMessageFilter.scala:49)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.apply(LogMessages.scala:33)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.apply(LogMessages.scala:28)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.applyOrElse(LogMessages.scala:28)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:502)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager.aroundReceive(JobManager.scala:122)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Registration name clash. KvState with name 'XXXX' has already been registered by another operator (fab4c54085fa3ee85a6e1bb1062c20af).
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.query.KvStateLocationRegistry.notifyKvStateRegistered(KvStateLocationRegistry.java:116)
    ... 20 more
```

When I run the job from the IntelliJ IDE, it works well, but when I run the job using the following command then I face this issue.

> bin/flink run -c com.xxx.XXXJob

What should be the reason for this error?
I have restarted flink and rerun the job but I'm still getting this error.

Comment: Which Flink version are you running?

Comment: I found the problems

Comment: I am using 1.4.2 flink

Comment: You can share the solution by answering your own question.

Comment: Sure. I will do it

Answer (score 1):

I have configured the same name of the queryable state in two process function.

```
    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) {
        ValueStateDescriptor<? super Output> descriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor(queryableStateName, Xyz.class);
        descriptor.setQueryable("downloads");
        state = getRuntimeContext().getState(descriptor);
    }
```

In above code `descriptor.setQueryable("downloads");` where I had given `downloads` in multiple process function.

Regarding my surprising about why it is running from `IDE` and not through `bin/flink run` command.

So the reason is the `'flink-queryable-state-runtime_2.11-1.4.2.jar'`

When I run from the IDE, IDE could not find this jar from the classpath. So queryable feature is disabled and due to that job never complains. So job runs successfully.

But when I use `bin/flink run` then it found from the flink's lib.

So it gives an error due to same name and job goes fail.